# Same Domain WordPress login on different server wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, dns

Quick Question.
A guest house was bought by the original owner and scenario as follows.

The Website for that guesthouse is on its own Hosted WordPress installation at the current host
The login address would be 
https://Example/wp-admin

I re-created that user account on our hosted WHM as I need to transfer the website and Domain to myself.

Can I login to the newly created WP-admin **on my server** while the A record is Pointed to the **current hosts IP?**

Example
**Current Host**
Example/WP-admin
IP:46.0.0.0

Example
**New Host**
Example/WP-admin
IP:76.0.0.0

How Can I login to the WP on the **new host** if the DNS is pointing to the
 IP:46.0.0.0 (**Current Host**)

FYI - most will ask why don't I point the A record, that's because the current host does not have the logins for the Cpanel, nor are they answering calls

THANKS,
hope this makes sense in the way I phrased it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your local machine you can change the hosts file to point Example webstie to 76.0.0.0 and then you can flush the dns cache and web browser cache. From now on Example website will point to 76.0.0.0 for your computer only. If you have a Windows machine and admin access, you can modify the hosts file under c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts ( change c partition to the partition that you have installed your windows on, if its different then "c" ) then you can add following line:

```
76.0.0.0 example.com www.example.com
```

Please make sure you flush the dns cache and clear the web browser cache afterwards.

If you want the whole world to see Example website from 76.0.0.0 you would have to change the A record.

Comment: Uggghhhh ofcourse, i completely forgot about the host file...... thanks a million rookie mistake thanks again